# Errors in Eclipse LogCat - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, logcat

Can somebody help me? I'm making a simple Android app which has splash screen and main menu with a button, which should lead to the other "page" and maybe play a sound. The app starts for a second, splash screen appears then the app crashes.. I have also noticed that it takes a while for button to load the other page :

I think this line has something to do with it :

```
12-05 23:36:57.710: I/ActivityManager(287): Displayed com.example.prva/.button: +1s167ms
```

And these are the red errors that appear constantly :

```
    12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0c8d8 that was originally bound here
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0c8d8 that was originally bound here
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-07 14:24:28.301: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587): null
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0c8d8 that was originally bound here
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-07 14:24:28.312: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-07 14:24:28.312: W/ActivityManager(273): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f409d8
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5ed58 that was originally bound here
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5ed58 that was originally bound here
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-07 14:24:28.322: E/ActivityThread(587):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587): null
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d5ed58 that was originally bound here
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-07 14:24:28.341: E/StrictMode(587):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I can post more info if needed, thank you in advance!

My MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer MPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);        

        MPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splash);
        MPlayer.start();        

        Thread tajmer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int tajmer = 0;
                    while(tajmer == 0)
                    {
                        sleep(3500);
                        tajmer = tajmer +1;
                    }
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meni_Splash.class));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }           

        };
        tajmer.start();     


    }




    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        MPlayer.release();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        MPlayer.pause();
    }   




    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        MPlayer.start();
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is a Meni_Splash.java code :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Meni_Splash extends Activity{

    MediaPlayer ButtonClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        //Button click sound
        final MediaPlayer ButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button1);



        Button btnv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonv);
        btnv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.prva.BUTTONVELIKI"));
                ButtonClick.start();
            }
        });

        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.prva.BUTTONPLAY"));
                ButtonClick.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My manifest (I think i messed everything up here and everywhere else...) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prva"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity            
            android:name="com.example.prva.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Meni_Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>         

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/simplyfit">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"        
        android:text="@string/pozdrav" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"        
        android:background="@drawable/button_v"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/buttonv"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

button.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/splash">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text2"
         android:text="@string/strana2"
         android:textSize="30sp"
         android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonplay"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
         android:text="@string/textbuttonplay"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

button.java :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class button extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.button);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the logcat but can you also post the code where this seems to be happening? Probably the onClickListener for your button and possibly where that leads to

Comment: I have edited the question and added the listener code!

Comment: What is the code at line number 37 of your Meni_Splash.java file? That is where some variable is null.

Comment: show to us the code of ``Meni_Splash.java`` there's wrong in line 37.

Comment: added meni_splash. Thank you guys for helping! looking forward to solving this...

Comment: Where are you calling the Meni_Splash activity?

Comment: Declare Meni_Splash in manifest as <activity
            android:name="com.example.prva.Meni_Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            
        </activity>

Comment: ^ its already declared in that way (i think)

 <activity
            
            android:name="com.example.prva.Meni_Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >


@codeMagic im using meni_splash to display a default menu after the splash screen which i made in main. now i was trying to make sounds on button clicks on the meni_splash and thats when everything went to hell (i have also added my main.java now in my first post)

Comment: In your MainActivity, try taking the startActivity out of the background thread and do it on the main thread. As a rule of thumb try to avoid interacting with the UI from a background thread.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Do what exactly? I'm stuck. I think the problem is somwhere in that play button but I can't see it myself. I have posted the button.xml and I made button.java tried few things..im lost. Still same error.

Comment: @user1880779 You are passing the play button object in Meni_Splash activity but the play button is not available in activity_main.xml file so this will give you null pointer exception.

Comment: @monkybonk05 How do I do it on the main thread in a way so it is done after the background thread is completely finished. If I do the StartActivity on the main thread it just skips the background thread and the splash screen.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya you were right, I managed to fix the fatal exception error but all the other errors are still there. The application is working fine but I'm worried about all of those massive errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write below code

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meni_Splash.class));
```

instead of

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.prva.MENU"));
```

And Write below code into your androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prva"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity            
            android:name="com.example.prva.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Meni_Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />              
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>         

    </application>

</manifest>
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: I replaced the StartActivity code and pasted the Manifest you wrote.

I'm still getting this (app crashes) :       

`12-06 12:40:45.002: E/AndroidRuntime(804): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 12:40:45.002: E/AndroidRuntime(804): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prva/com.example.prva.Meni_Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 12:40:45.002: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-06 12:40:45.002: E/AndroidRuntime(804):  at`

etc. etc.

Comment: Still doesn't work :

`12-06 12:46:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 12:46:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prva/com.example.prva.Meni_Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 12:46:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-06 12:46:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at 
12-06 12:46:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-06 12:46:44.243: E/AndroidRuntime(881)`

Answer (score 0):

try:
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meni_Splash.class));